# How to deselect Primeng Selection Table (TS)

Tags: html, angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-datatable

I want to reset the selected rows to all deselect via TS. Resetting the table does not update the selected rows.

```
<p-table [value]="groups" [(selection)]="selectedgroups">
```

TS:

```
import { Table } from 'primeng/table';

@ViewChild(Table) dataTableComponent: Table;
selectedgroups = [];

resetTable() {
  this.dataTableComponent?.reset();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reset table by assigning empty value to selected-groups property

```
resetTable() {
        this. selectedgroups = [];
}
```